# php / js facebook API Internet explorer fb_xd_fragment

Tags: php, internet-explorer, facebook, api

I'm debugging my website on Internet Explorer and, each time I try to use Facebook and connect with IE, it logs me in with Facebook, but in the popup it changes the URL to something beginning with "fb_xd_fragment" and it doesn't set the cookies for my domain...

Any idea how to fix this? It only happens on IE, works perfectly on FF/Chrome/Safari.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the cross document communication is not working for you. Do you have a URL where I can see the issue in action? One work around is to specify a custom channel URL: http://wiki.github.com/facebook/connect-js/custom-channel-url

Comment: this link is broken now... what was it / what's the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the information on: http://blog.colnect.com/2010/10/fbxdfragment-bug-workaround.html